# Sinatra - how to match production urls with the app's urls

Tags: sinatra, url-routing, production-environment

Consider the following simple Sinatra application:

```
require 'sinatra'
post '/user/login' do
  # login logic...
end
```

When deploying the application to a production environment, the url `/user/login` is usually changed to something else, i.e.,  `/nitro/nutcracker/v1/user/login`. And of course, the Sinatra app will not serve this url.

To cut the unwanted prefix, I've considered using a filter (i.e., `before` block), and routes with regex (i.e., `get /*/user/login`), but surely there are better solutions?

What say you?

Answer (score 1):

You can mount it with rack. On the production server, create a config.ru file, and put this inside:

```
require_relative 'my_app.rb'
map('/nitro/nutcracker/v1/') { run Sinatra::Application } # Or your class, if it's modular
```

This will prefix the entire app with `/nitro/nutcracker/v1/`.

Then you run the server with `rackup`, or your application server might have a command line argument to pass a rack config file.

Comment: Thanks :-) that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it's what you were looking for